# Can I assign Enterprise Keyword to blog posts in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: managed-metadata, blog

I want to use Enterprise Keywords also for blog posts.
I've created a sub-site and used as design "Blog".
Now I have my blog, but I do not see a way to activate the Enterprise Keywords metadata from the term store.

How can I do that?

I would like to also ask how to make these tags visible when you are viewing the blog post, not just when viewing the list of blog posts. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enable `Enterprise Metadata` for Posts follow the steps below:

- go to `Blogs` list
- select `List Settings` and then `Enterprise Metadata and Keywords
  Settings` , enable `Enterprise Keywords`

Comment: thanks a lot. However, in my SharePoint 2013 with a blog-subsite, the names of the elements were a little different - I've edited your post. (The list is called "posts" and is accessible in the site contents of the Blog-subsite